# Figure out if a jar is running -- NOT OS Dependent

Tags: java, perl

I am looking for a solution to figure out if my .jar is already running.  However, I need this to be able to work on Windows, RedHat, Solaris, OEL, etc. A solution in perl would be great.  However, I would also be okay trying a solution where the jar is called and then in the main class checks to see if another jar is already running (and if it is, it shutsdown). I am calling it using `java -jar`

I looked into the following:  [How can I check if a Unix process is running in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844168/how-can-i-check-if-a-unix-process-is-running-in-perl) However it did not seem to work for Windows.

I also looked at this post:  [Using Perl, how do I check if a process with given name is running or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023781/using-perl-how-do-i-check-if-a-process-with-given-name-is-running-or-not)  However this would only work for Windows.

I suppose it would be possible to use a combination of the two after figuring out which OS the jar is running on, however I am looking for a 'cleaner' option.

Any help would be great.

Comment: To begin with, a Jar does not run. The JVM runs, and will load the jars in its classpath.

Comment: @SJuan76, A valid point. However, I would suggest that this question is still valid and should not be closed.

Comment: @Cameron, Please clarify, when you run 'your .jar' program, do you run it using `java -jar` syntax, or `java -cp`, or `javaw`, or double-click the file, or something else?

Comment: I am calling it using java -jar

Comment: @CameronJones when someone asks you a question in a comment, edit the answer into your question. That way people can answer you without having to read all the comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the java process status tool: `jps` that comes with the jdk.  It lists what's running, and if a program was launched like `java -jar start.jar` it will show you the name of the jar file:

```
root@MYBOX:/opt/jetty/logs# jps
31557 start.jar
1891 Jps
```

You could build your script around `jps` to see if your jar is already running

There are additional options you can give `jps` to print more or less data: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html

Comment: This worked great.  It seems to be working on Windows / Unix for now.  I think I will go ahead and use this unless for some reason it doesn't work on a specific OS.

Comment: @CameronJones should work on any system that Java can work on, since `jps` is part of the JDK.  Note that it's not part of the JRE though :(

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution would be to write the status of the program in a text file or a database and  read it when you want to know the state of your application.

As George mentionned, writing in the text file every second (for example) could let you see easily if the program is stuck if nothing was written for, let's say, the last 5 seconds.

Also, a text file is OS independent :-)

Comment: If the Java program updates the text file every few seconds, then if the program failed abnormally, you could detect this by knowing that the updates have stopped happening.

Answer (score 0):

Java could be running the `jar` directly (`java -jar foo.jar`), or it could be that the jar contains classes that the Java program you are running requires.

The first is easy enough. You can use `jps` which will show you all of the Java commands running.

The second is harder. You can't even depend upon the value of `$CLASSPATH` or see what the `-cp` parameter was when you executed the Java program. The jar may be mentioned in that classpath, but not needed, or the jar is mentioned in the classpath of the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file embedded in one of your jars that is being used.